# decode json data into string using query

Tags: mysql, json, phpmyadmin

Hi i am using phpmyadmin mysql

In one of my database table i have a column contact_email and the value is stored as below

```
contact_email
["ass@sss.ib"]
```

Which is Json encoded data , I am trying to convert that encoded data into string using query

I tried qith **JSON_extract**  but it gave error.

Output what i need is

From **["ass@sss.ib"]** to **ass@sss.ib**

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Simple use something like that

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( '{ "name": "John" }' );
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```